# erro instalar a virtualenv no python

Tags: python, linux, pip, virtualenv

Eu não consigo criar a virtualenv, eu dei uma pesquisada ensinando como instalar e qdo eu rodo o install dela da esse erro aqui

versão Python 3.8.3

```
> root@AlexPc:/# apt install python3-virtualenv Lendo listas de
> pacotes... Pronto Construindo árvore de dependências        Lendo
> informação de estado... Pronto Alguns pacotes não puderam ser
> instalados. Isto pode significar que você solicitou uma situação
> impossível ou, se você está usando a distribuição instável, que alguns
> pacotes requeridos não foram criados ainda ou foram retirados da
> "Incoming". A informação a seguir pode ajudar a resolver a situação:
> 
> Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas: 
> python3-virtualenv : Depende: python3-distutils mas não é instalável
>                       Depende: python3-importlib-metadata mas não é instalável
>                       Depende: python3-appdirs mas não é instalável E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.*
```

e se eu tento instalar pelo python mais antigo que instalei tb pra testar da esse erro

versão Python 2.7.18rc1

```
> root@AlexPc:/# apt install python-virtualenv Lendo listas de
> pacotes... Pronto Construindo árvore de dependências        Lendo
> informação de estado... Pronto O pacote python-virtualenv não está
> disponível, mas é referenciado por outro pacote. Isto pode significar
> que o pacote está faltando, ficou obsoleto ou está disponível somente
> a partir de outra fonte
> 
> E: O pacote 'python-virtualenv' não tem candidato para instalação
> root@AlexPc:/#
```

se eu tento instalar com o pip aparece essa msg

```
> root@AlexPc:/home/alex# pip install virtualenv
> 
> O comando 'pip' não foi encontrado, mas existem 18 semelhantes.
> 
> root@AlexPc:/home/alex#
```

e se eu tento instalar o pip tanto em qq versão do python aparece isso

```
> root@AlexPc:/home/alex# sudo apt install python-pip Lendo listas de
> pacotes... Pronto Construindo árvore de dependências        Lendo
> informação de estado... Pronto E: Impossível encontrar o pacote
> python-pip root@AlexPc:/home/alex# sudo apt install python3-pip Lendo
> listas de pacotes... Pronto Construindo árvore de dependências       
> Lendo informação de estado... Pronto Alguns pacotes não puderam ser
> instalados. Isto pode significar que você solicitou uma situação
> impossível ou, se você está usando a distribuição instável, que alguns
> pacotes requeridos não foram criados ainda ou foram retirados da
> "Incoming". A informação a seguir pode ajudar a resolver a situação:
> 
> Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:  python3-pip :
> Depende: python3-distutils mas não é instalável
>                Depende: python3-setuptools mas não é instalável
>                Recomenda: python3-dev (>= 3.2) mas não é instalável E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.
> root@AlexPc:/home/alex#
```

meu OS é Linux - ubuntu

Comment: Talvez você já tenha feito algo errado e destruído a possiblidade de atualizar pacotes de Python da sua distribuição. Voce tem uma chance de ainda funcionar `python3 -m venv` aí - isso faz exatamente o mesmo que  `virtualenv` em Pythons mais novos.  `python3 -m venv env` cria um virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos começar instalando o pip. No seu terminal insira:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

Com o pip instalado, vamos instalar o virtualenv e o virtualwrapper:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

Agora vamos configurar o ambiente. Você precisa encontrar o arquivo ~/.bashrc. 
Vá na sua /home pelo navedor de arquivos mesmo e pressione ctrl+H para ver os arquivos ocultos. Você vai ver o arquivo .bashrc. 
No final dele insira:

```
# local onde os ambientes serão armazenados
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
# Local do python para o qual o virtualenv foi instalado (no caso Python3)
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
# Adicionar os comandos virtualenvwrapper no bash
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
# define que não é possível utilizar o pip fora de algum ambiente virtual
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
```

Agora vamos criar um virtualenv para testar se deu tudo certo. Abra um novo terminal e insira:

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.8 ambiente_teste
```

A flag -p indica uma versão específica do python para o seu ambiente virtual. Se não passar uma versão, a versão padrão do sistema será utilizada. Você poderia ter passado apenas `mkvirtualenv ambiente_teste`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Se você utiliza o linux, você deve instalar o `virtualenv` pelo `apt-get`

Segue o commando para instalação:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualenv
```

Após instalar o virtualenv é possível utilizar o pip.

Para iniciar o ambiente com python3, basta executar o comando:

```
$ virtualenv env -p $(which python3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deu certo  o que o Vitor Guimarães respondeu, só que tive que instalar pelo python2.7.18rc1. Acho que o python3 do meu pc ta zuado msm, segue abaixo o que fiz

```
> wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

seguido do comando

```
> sudo python get-pip.py
```

depois no home abri o arquivo -> .bashrc  -> e colei no final dele

```
# local onde os ambientes serão armazenados
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
# Local do python para o qual o virtualenv foi instalado (no caso Python)
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
# Adicionar os comandos virtualenvwrapper no bash
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
# define que não é possível utilizar o pip fora de algum ambiente virtual
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
```

e por ultimo para criar usei o comando

> `virtualenv nomeDoVirtualenv`

seguido do comando e pra testar ativei a virtualenv com o comando

> `source nomeDoVirtualenv/bin/activate`

depois sai dele com o comando

> `deactivate`

Muito obrigado a todos que me ajudaram vcs são tops
Forte Abraço - vlw